# Getting access to VRay Python SDK

Tags: python, sdk, render, maya, autodesk

I'm developing some Python scripts to read/parse/process some .vrscene files.

From others' examples, I can see that there is a Python SDK for VRay called vrayutils.

I want to get this information from the `SettingsOutput` object.

From a .vrscene file I want to get the total frame numbers.

Does anyone know where I can get that Python library or how I can call it?

Comment: Please state what you have tried and failed/succeeded at.

Comment: Finally i achieved to do some things by reading the file and extracting the things i needed.

Comment: Provide that as an answer. It might be helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do some of the things by parsing the file using basic Python and then extracting the things I needed.

The V-Ray API has a proprietary license, and there is no open source way to access the .vrscene

I decided to try with a trial version of the SDK, and by using the SDK you will be able to find a nice Python build wrapped with a bunch of examples within the V-Ray Application SDK.

The price is 1250 euro annually for a single development license (for one server node).

Support is included.

They can give you a preliminary evaluation version for 3 months under NDA (What I used).

No reverse engineering is permitted so if you are planning to develop over V-Ray you should buy it.